# Match input value and array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am confusing about match the input value and array.

I have a input box which can enter author name:

```
<b>Author's name:</b> 
<input type="text"  name="authorName">
```

And there are three authors in total, and I put them in an array:

```
var authorName =["a","b","c"];
```

There are three books match these authors in a drop down list:

```
<b>Select Book:</b>
<select name="selectBook" id="bookName">
<option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
<option id="bookA"value="q">My Decade In The Premier League</option>
<option id="bookB"value="r">Harry Potter</option>
<option id="bookC"value="s">Twilight</option>
</select>
```

Here is a textarea to show the information of the book;

If user input "a" and choose drop down list "q", give the information "x";

If user input "b" and choose drop down list "r", give the information "y";

if user input "c" and choose drop down list "s", give the information "z";

```
<br>
<input type="button" value="RETRIEVE">
<br> 
<textarea name="infoBox"></textarea>
```

If the input name is not in the array or not match the book name.

The textarea box will output `"author name is incorrect!"`

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What makes this question different from the previous one?

Comment: Cause I think i didn't tell clearly in the previous one. So the answer cannot solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. When the answers are submitted it checks to see if the  value is in your array and that it matches the book description. Then returns a yes or a no

```
var authorName =["a","b","c"];

$("#retrieve").click(function(){

  var selectedAuthor = $(".author-name").val();
  var selectedBook = $("#bookName").children(":selected").attr("id");;

  if( ($.inArray(selectedAuthor, authorName) > -1) && (selectedBook == "book-"+selectedAuthor) ) {

    $("#results").val("YEP ITS A MATCH");
  }else{
    $("#results").val("SORRY, NO MATCH");

  }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9dx49k0/1/)

**UPDATE**

displays selected book:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9dx49k0/4/)

**NEW UPDATE**
Added a seperate array for book info:

[NEW FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/c9dx49k0/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This shows the author and book name match or not, but if match how to give different book information? I am a freshman in javascript. Sorry

Comment: @MarkMao no problem, i added a new fiddle that shows which book was selected if there is a match

Comment: I see, but the problem is there is another array store book information(x,y,z), if match it should give "x" or "y" or"z" as a result...thank you so so much.

Comment: @MarkMao ok gotcha, I created a new fiddle that does that. you can either embed the js right into the html file or you can create a separate js file and link to it from the html file.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work

```
          $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#RETRIEVE").click(
            function () {
                retrieve();
            }            
        );
    });

function retrieve() {
    var authorName =["a","b","c"];
    var text = $('#authorName').val();
    var drop= $('#bookName :selected').text();
  if ((authorName.indexOf(text) != -1) && $("#bookName").get(0).selectedIndex-1== $.inArray(text,authorName))

        $('#infoBox').val(drop);

    else        
       $('#infoBox').val("Incorrect name");


}
```

the Jsfiddle for the above is [http://jsfiddle.net/yzqqr8ws/](http://jsfiddle.net/yzqqr8ws//)

Comment: sorry I wrongly understood your question. I will rectify it now

Comment: this doesnt match the author to the book, it only checks to see if the authors name is correct